# Plot ARM general-purpose registers

Tags: plot, arm, waveform, arm7

I have had looking for some app capable to emulate ARM7 instructions and plot the registers values along time. I tried µVision IDE 5, but it seems not possible. Do you have any app suggestion?

Comment: The search term you want is "instruction set simulator" - there are quite a few.

Comment: @Notlikethat almost, in some apps I could see the changes in registers, but in "real time", not along the time.